# Jump to top/bottom of a file in VS for Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio

I cannot find any shortcut to let me jump to the bottom (or top) of a code file when using Visual Studio for Mac. It's quite an annoyance not being able to easily do this, is there a shortcut?

(I have Home/End mapped to their Windows behaviour start/end of line not the default Mac behaviour)?

Comment: What does Control+Home and Control+End do on your Mac? (On Windows, those combinations go to the start or end of the file.)

Comment: @AdrianMole they act as if Ctrl wasn't pressed, I should've said I tried that already.

Comment: OK - How about "Command+Home"? (In many cases, a Windows Ctrl+X is replaced by Cmd+X on the Mac.)

Answer (score 0):

During my testing on macOS Ventura 13.5 with Visual Studio Code 1.83.0, the following key sequences worked for me:

```
<CMD><Up-Arrow>: Jump to top of file
<CMD><Down-Arrow>: Jump to bottom of file.
```

Let's say that you are positioned in the middle of a log file, and you want select all lines from your current position to the top or bottom of a file, the following key sequences worked for me:

```
<SHIFT><CMD><Up-Arrow>: Select all text from here to the top of file
<SHIFT><CMD><Down-Arrow>: Select all text from here to the bottom of file
```